# Trouble with changing pointer values

Tags: c

So I started learning C today and have had no problems making it through tutorial exercises, but I am finally stuck. I have checked stackoverflow, other reddit posts, and youtube videos. I am trying to created a linked list. Below is my code with detailed comments of what I think the code is doing. When I run this in CLion, there is no output from the printList function. However, if I uncomment the lines that are slashed out (there's only 3 of them, easy to find) and I comment out my call to push(), the printList function prints 1, as it should. As far as I understand, the 3 commented lines and the lines in push() are doing the same thing, so why is the output different?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <malloc.h>

typedef struct node {
    int val;
    struct node *next;
} node_t; //node struct is defined

void printList(node_t *head); //printlist function is initialized, accepts a node_t pointer (correct vocabulary?)
void push(node_t *head, int val); //push function is initialized

int main() {
    node_t *head = NULL; //a pointer is created that points to a struct of type node_t, and currently points to NULL
    push(head, 1); //push function accepts node_t pointer which currently points to NULL, and an int: 1
//    head = (node_t *) malloc(sizeof(node_t)); //the pointer "head" now points to a section of memory that can
    //hold a node_t struct
//    head->val = 1; //head's "val" variable now points to the int 1
//    head->next = NULL; // head's "next" variable now points to NULL
    printList(head);
    return 0;
}

void printList(node_t *head) {
    node_t *current = head;
    while (current != NULL) {
        printf("%d ", current->val);
        current = current->next;
    }
}

void push(node_t *head, int val) {
    node_t *current = head; //the pointer "current" now points to the value that head pointed to (NULL)
    current = (node_t *) malloc(sizeof(node_t)); //just enough memory is allocated for a node_t struct,
    // and the variable current now points to it
    current->val = val; //current's "val" variable now points to the int "val" from the function parameters
    current->next = NULL; //current's "next" variable, which is a node_t pointer, now points to NULL

}
```

Comment: You're not changing the *head* outside the `push`; `head` in `push` is a local variable.

Comment: One part of the problem: You do `current = head` directly followed by `current = malloc(...)`. Now where do `current` point after the second assignment?

Comment: Another part of the problem: Do a search for *emulating pass by reference in c*.

Comment: I thought that head and current both point to the same memory address, therefore changing the value at that address from within the push function would mean that the head variable in main is pointing to the newly changed data.

Comment: When you **pass** a pointer to a function, the function receives a **copy** of the pointer (with its very own, and very differed address from the pointer you pass in `main`. (if you have already allocated, no big deal, it already holds an address as its value) If you are allocating in `push`, You either (1) **return** and assign the new pointer value to `head` in `main`; or (2) pass the address of `head` to `push` (e.g. `void push (note_t **head, int val) {...}` and call it by `push (&head, 1)`.

Comment: 'I have checked stackoverflow' well, I have to say that about half of all linked-list questins on SO have that problem of updating only local vars :((

Answer (score 3):

Continuing from the comment, if you are going to use a `void` function rather than returning `node_t *` and assigning to `head`, you need to pass the **address of** `head` to `push`? Why? When you allocate for `current` in `push`, it has its own address and has no relation to `head` in `main`.

When you assign `node_t *current = head;` you are assigning a **copy of head** (not head itself) to `current`. Now, the copy is initialized to `NULL`, but the address of the pointer `head` in `push` is *not the same* as `head` in `main`.

What did you pass to `push`? (ans: a copy of `head`, e.g. a `NULL` pointer) `head` in `push` has a separate and distinct *pointer address* to the `head` in `main`. When `push` returns, you have no reference to either pointer in `push` (`head` or `current`) because `current` was declared within `push` and the address for the copy of `head` in push, created by the compiler when `head` was passed as a parameter, is also gone. To make `head` in `push` have the same address as `head` in `main`, pass its address to `push`, e.g.

```
int main (void) {

    node_t *head = NULL;

    push (&head, 1);
    printList (head);

    putchar ('\n'); /* tidy up */

    return 0;
}
...
void push(node_t **head, int val) 
{
    node_t *current =  malloc(sizeof *current);
    current->val = val;
    current->next = NULL;
    *head = current;
}
```

Let me know if you have further questions.

---

You can also return a pointer (type `node_t *`) and assign in `main`, e.g.

```
int main (void) {

    node_t *head = NULL;

    head = push (1);
    printList (head);

    putchar ('\n'); /* tidy up */

    return 0;
}
...
node_t *push(int val) 
{
    node_t *current =  malloc(sizeof *current);

    current->val = val;
    current->next = NULL;

    return current;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the key problem is you pass a pointer by value not by address. So when the caller exits, the value of the pointer (head) doesn't change at all!

you can change the `push` like this:

```
void push(node_t **head, int val) {
(*head) = (node_t *) malloc(sizeof(node_t)); //just enough memory is allocated for a node_t struct,
(*head)->val = val; //current's "val" variable now points to the int "val" from the function parameters
(*head)->next = NULL; //current's "next" variable, which is a node_t pointer, now points to NULL
}
```

then you can call it like this: `push(&head, 1);`

in this example, I pass `head` by address and update its value in `push` function by dereference. So its change can be seen out of the `push` function.

Hope it helps!

(my first answer on stackoverflow :P)